Error while unziping a file from a pendrive from windows on linux mint
I recently (today) installed Linux Mint for the first time. I made my backup on a pendrive, but when I tried unzipping the backup file I made, it gave me the following error:
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of backup.zip or
        backup.zip.zip, and cannot find backup.zip.ZIP, period.

I tried seeing what I could do on the forums. Apparently, it means my file is corrupted. The thing is I can normally access the files from my pendrive without taking it to my PC.
OBS.: A detail I judged to be useful is that when I installed Linux, I forgot to take the USB stick out. I don't think this is the cause of the problem, but who knows.
UPDATE: I tried taking the file on a windows computer, it was not a .zip, it was a .rar, sorry for the inconvenience.

sounds like your zip file is broken. My bet is 100% on a broken USB thumb drive, which nobody can do anything about.

Rather than a broken usb thumb drive, did you perhaps pull out the usb thumb drive without first ejecting it?  The zip file may not have finished writing before you pulled it out.

I ejected it before pulling out, and waited a bit before ejecting.
